# Chrome add to desktop: icon not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, icons, desktop

Chrome: the icon meta is not used for "adding to desktop" on windows laptop.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Example Application</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
     <link rel="icon" sizes="500x400" href="/icon.png">
   </head>
   <body>
   Hello, Great day!

   </body>
</html>
```

But it is used for "add to home screen" on android device. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">`?

Comment: Just tried with "shortcut icon" with png file, not working. But I did not try .ico file.

Comment: Did you get this working? For me it is just a dark grey background with a letter in the icon box

Answer (score 0):

I had commented on this earlier. But, I was able to get an icon in the "Add to Desktop" tool within Chrome. 
For a long time it wouldn't work for me, but my resolution was 150x136 (not sure why, but that was the original I was given). I then tried using a program, Gimp for example, to change the resolution to be square (136x136 to be exact). Then it worked!
So, my suggestion is to make your icon perfectly square and then refresh your page (crtl+shift+R) and try again. 
[image]

Comment: This icon only shows up on this add dialog. But once the Add button is clicked, the shortcut that gets created does not have this icon; it has the old gray icon with the webpage's initial character.